# OpenCV: detecting lines with small curvature

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

In OpenCV, I want to detect straight lines in my image. However, I want this to be robust to two things: small "wiggles" along the line, and small curvature of the entire line.

I know that OpenCV supports detecting straight lines with the Hough transform (http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html). However, if the line has some small wiggles in it, or if there is a small amount of curvature along the line, then each part of the line will "vote" for different line parameters.

How can I make this function robust to the wiggles and curves?

Comment: Can you show a few images?